# How to use values from porperty files in a global context with Junit5 and CitrusExtension

Tags: junit, properties, junit5, citrus-framework

Maybe I'm on the wrong course or totally misunderstanding something.

I've merged a Citrus IntegrationTest from Junit4Runner to Junit5 (with CitrusExtension).

There is an *EndpointConfiguration* class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("test-setup.properties")
@PropertySource("service-paths.properties")
public class RestEndpointConfig {
    @Value("${testenv.host}") //defined in test-setup.properties
    private String host;
...
}
```

And a TestClass

```
@ExtendWith(CitrusExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class BaseIT{
    @CitrusEndpoint
    protected HttpClient httpClient;
    @Value("${rest.session}") //defined in service-paths.properties
    private String sessionPath;
}
```

In the test class I want to access values defined in the *service-paths.properties* file.
This worked with JUnit4 but after the changes to JUnit5 it seems that the properties are no longer available in a 'global' context.
Turning the log level to 'debug' shows, that the properties file is loaded.

So my question is: What do I need to change in order to get access to the *service-paths* properies in my IT classes. What am I missing, what is best practice in this case?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Property value resolving via `@Value` annotation is a core Spring framework feature. So you need to add SpringExtension to your JUnit5 test. You can do this in addition to using the CitrusExtension.